# How to find a single element in a vector?

Tags: rust

In a vector with a) unique elements b) non unique ones

how does one find a single element?

Should I use filter and then get the 1st element from a result? Is there a more idiomatic way?

**update 1**

I haven't been able to make this compile:

```
let elems = create_btree_map_data(); //BTreeMap<i32, MyStruct>

//let elem = elems.iter().find(&&|k, v| v.status == Status::Good);
//let elem = elems.iter().find(|&k, &v| v.status == Status::Good);
//let elem = elems.iter().find(|&&k, &&v| v.status == Status::Good);

//let elem = elems.iter().find(&|k, v| v.status == Status::Good);
```

That is, I haven't been able to complitely dereference  `v` to be able to apply a predicte to it.

Comment: [`.iter().find(…)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.find)

Comment: That is definitely not a vector. Anyway: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=601682c936dc5d9ec1daa9e89de50e67 Also, iterating over BTreeMaps is a sign that you're using them wrong, but I couldn't say for sure with more context.

Comment: @Caesar, god damn it. I don't know why I'm iterating over `BTreeMap`. You're right